# Concerning the conversion of an essential supremum to a pointwise estimate

Tags: measure-theory, semigroups-of-operators, potential-theory

In the following paper :

*Chen, Zhen-Qing; Kumagai, Takashi; Wang, Jian*, [**Stability of parabolic Harnack inequalities for symmetric non-local Dirichlet forms**](https://doi.org/10.4171/JEMS/996), J. Eur. Math. Soc. (JEMS) 22, No. 11, 3747-3803 (2020). [ZBL1455.35004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1455.35004),

the definition of the parabolic Harnack inequality is given in Definition 1.1. More precisely, it is a statement of the form :
$$
\mbox{esssup}_{Q-} u \leq C_6\mbox{essinf}_{Q+} u.
$$
Here, $Q-,Q+ \subset ([0,\infty) \times X,m \otimes \mu)$, where $(X,\mu)$ is some measure space, $\mu$ has full support, and $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. The function $u: I \times X \to \mathbb R$ is a caloric function, whose definition of this is provided in (i),Definition 1.13 of the paper. Given a Hunt process $X$ with associated semigroup $P_tf(x) = \mathbb E_x[f(X_t)]$, the function $u(t, x) = P_tf(x)$ is an example of a caloric function. However, there is no regularity property of the function $u$ that is yet apparent at this point.

In Proposition 3.1 of the same paper, the authors proceed to assume that a process satisfies the Parabolic Harnack inequality, and say that they apply the inequality to the aforementioned $u(t,x) 
= P_tf(x)$ for some fixed nice choice of $f$. Then comes the very first displayed equation :
$$
P_{(C_1+C_2)\phi(r)/2}f(x) \leq C_6 P_{(C_3+C_4)\phi(r)/2}f(y),
$$
for all $x,y$ outside some "exceptional" set depending upon $u$. I am unsure how this statement is derived, given that it is possible that $(C_1+C_2)\phi(r)/2,x)$ and $((C_3+C_4)\phi(r)/2,y)$ could lie in the $m \otimes \mu$-measure zero sets in which $\mbox{esssup}_{Q-} f < P_{(C_1+C_2)\phi(r)/2}f(x)$ and $P_{(C_3+C_4)\phi(r)/2}f(y) < \mbox{essinf}_{Q+} f$.

Typically, if $u$ was a function such that, removing a set of $m \otimes \mu$ measure zero, it was jointly continuous in both variables, then removing that set will lead to the estimate above. However, while for a *fixed* value of $T$, it is possible to find $N \subset X$ such that $\mu(N) = 0$ and $u(T,\cdot)$ is continuous on $X \setminus N$ ($P_Tf(\cdot)$ admits a quasi-continuous version for fixed $t$), the problem is that here the estimate seems to apply at particular times $T_1$ and $T_2$ and particular points $x,y$ outside some set, and it's unclear as to how the essential supremum is simplified to a pointwise estimate. Also note that I cannot "patch" the null sets of different times together because there are uncountably many of them.

Perhaps I'm missing something quite obvious, because this merited little to no explanation from the authors of the paper, and the step remains the same throughout the five versions of the paper on arXiv. The relevant proposition has been cited by a few authors in the meantime, therefore it is important to understand that particular step.